# Devise after_sign_in_path_for works, but not the other ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm really missing something here.

I have read many things about devise redirects (seems like it is hard to implement for most people ...) but in my case I really don't get it.

Sometimes I read that the methods `after_<action>_path_for(resource)` should be in the `ApplicationController`, sometimes it is mentionned to be in a specific controller, overriding the devise one.

I'd rather have them in my `ApplicationController` since it bothers me to create more Controllers just for a redirect, but if it is not possible at the end, I won't insist...

Here's the deal:

I have in my `ApplicationController` : (and some others, but that's enough for the example)

```
  def after_update_path_for(user)
    flash[:notice] = 'Successfully updated password'
    edit_user_path(user)
  end

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(user)
    flash[:notice] = 'Welcome! Please follow the steps!'
    me_new_path
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
    flash[:notice] = 'Welcome! Please follow the steps!'
    me_new_path
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    if user.sign_in_count == 1
      me_new_path
    else
      root_path
    end
  end
```

And the crazy thing, is that `after_sign_in_path_for` is called, but not the other ones. Like when the user signs up it's the `if user.sign_in_count == 1` that redirects him, not the `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` nor the `after_sign_up_path_for`

**How come?**

It could be related to my routes, so here's my `routes.rb` extract:

```
  devise_for :user, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations], :path => ''
  devise_scope :user do
    get :register, :to => 'devise/registrations#new'
    post :register, :to => 'devise/registrations#create'
    put :update_password, :to => 'devise/my_registrations#update'
    get :login, :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
    get :login, :to => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_copasser_session
    post :login, :to => 'devise/sessions#create'
    delete :logout, :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
```

And I'm using Devise 3.1.0 with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.13

Thanks for the help!

---

**EDIT**

Thanks @rich-peck for your answer. I updated my `routes.rb` this way :

```
  devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { 
    :sign_in => :login,
    :registration => :register,
    :sign_up => '',
    :sign_out => :logout
  }
```

which gives me the same routes as the previous ones (except I can't use `login_path` helper anymore but it's not a big deal), but I still get the same results concerning redirects.

Here is the result of `rake routes`:

```
                       new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)                                               devise/sessions#new
                           user_session POST   /login(.:format)                                               devise/sessions#create
                   destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)                                              devise/sessions#destroy
                          user_password POST   /password(.:format)                                            devise/passwords#create
                      new_user_password GET    /password/new(.:format)                                        devise/passwords#new
                     edit_user_password GET    /password/edit(.:format)                                       devise/passwords#edit
                                        PUT    /password(.:format)                                            devise/passwords#update
               cancel_user_registration GET    /register/cancel(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#cancel
                      user_registration POST   /register(.:format)                                            devise/registrations#create
                  new_user_registration GET    /register(.:format)                                            devise/registrations#new
                 edit_user_registration GET    /register/edit(.:format)                                       devise/registrations#edit
                                        PUT    /register(.:format)                                            devise/registrations#update
                                        DELETE /register(.:format)                                            devise/registrations#destroy
                      user_confirmation POST   /confirmation(.:format)                                        devise/confirmations#create
                  new_user_confirmation GET    /confirmation/new(.:format)                                    devise/confirmations#new
                                        GET    /confirmation(.:format)                                        devise/confirmations#show
```

Any idea?

Comment: You need to put the overrides in the right controllers as specified in the Devise docs. Not all can go in the ApplicationController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to @rich-peck's help, we figured it out.

The question was why do `after_sign_in_path_for` behave differently than `after_sign_up_path_for` and cie ?

It appears, [in the devise sources](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/9281ac39588c768a48197a3f5c283f07d40bc593/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb), that `after_sign_in_path_for` is defined in a helper, whereas the other ones are methods of their controller (eg. `Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController`)

Hence for `after_sign_in_path_for` it works overriding in the `ApplicationController`, whereas for the other ones, it is necessary to create a `registrations_controller.rb` file, to override the method in it:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(copasser)
    flash[:notice] = 'Welcome! Please follow the steps!'
    me_new_path
  end

end
```

and to set the `router.rb` this way:

```
devise_for :copassers, :controllers => { 
    :registrations => :registrations
  }
```

I suppose the behaviour is different because `:registerable, :recoverable` etc. are modules of devise, not necessarily used, and the helper wouldn't be appropriate in that case. A devise contributor could help us on this point.

Answer (score 1):

Devise relies heavily on a central variable called "resource". This variable defines how devise operates on your system, and is why you have to "attach" Devise to :users or similar

People get problems with Devise because they don't follow the conventions, and put their forms everywhere. If they read the Devise readme, they'd appreciate that it's quite flexible :)

I believe your problem is to do with your routes, in that you might want to consolidate all those static routes into something like this:

```
devise_for :users, :path => '', :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions', :registrations => 'registrations'}, :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :password => 'forgot', :confirmation => 'confirm', :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'register', :sign_up => 'new', :sign_out => 'logout'}
```

Comment: I updated my `routes.rb` and edited my question. But it still won't work. Any other idea? Thanks!

Comment: Hmmmmm, it might be worth jumping into chat for this if you've got some time?

Comment: Sure! How do I get started?

Comment: Let me know when you're online (just leave a comment), and I'll create a chatroom for us to go into!

Comment: Ping! :) (I'm in Europe)

Comment: I'm waiting there. But I understand if you are not available. Should we set an hour to talk?

Comment: Hey I'm sorry dude! We just had a problem with this Paperclip thing we were sorting out! I'll be on at 5:00PM UK time (I believe 6:00PM your time)? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39681/discussion-between-augustin-riedinger-and-rich-peck)